# Wortfolge "Mach ich."

Tags: word-order

> Kaufst du bitte Brot?
>
> Ja, **mach ich**.
>
> ---
>
> Hast du am Wochenende Zeit?
>
> Ja, **hab ich**.

Mich interessiert die Wortfolge in den Antwortsätzen. Wenn dies affirmative Sätze sind, warum haben wir dann die invertierte Wortfolge? Handelt es sich hier um elliptische Sätze, in denen direktes Objekt ausgelassen wird (*ja, **das** mache ich*) oder liege ich falsch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Im ersten Satz kann man das als verkürzte Sätze und Wörter auffassen:

> Ja, (das) mach(e) ich.

Beim zweiten Satz fällt das schon schwerer:

> Ja, (Zeit am Wochenende) hab(e) ich.

Eine derartige Formulierung wird man allenfalls Umgangssprachlich antreffen.

Möglicherweise wir hier auch einfach die Wortstellung der Frage übernommen: „Hast Du?“ → „Habe ich“.

Comment: besten Dank! =)

Comment: Wieso "allenfalls"? "Ja, hab' ich" und selbst "Hab' ich" sind doch prävalent.